# Django not collecting static files to S3 bucket but local directory, what's wrong with the config?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, collectstatic

So I have my `settings.py` set up as so:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_dir/static/')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

While I have looked for problems, nothing looks out of the blue. Though running collectstatic still does it locally rather than uploading it to my S3 bucket. Is there a particular configuration I'm missing, or just something in general?

I have the boto3 and storages installed.

Django 2.0.3

Thanks.

Comment: I presume you're using django-storages. Have you included `storages` in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yeah. And I've already put `storages` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @BobPoberton did you figure this out? I'm experiencing the same problem.